# API routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, razor

Alright so I am experiencing an issue with routing i think or something. I have followed the guides here in the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

I have also looked at a few other things here on stack overflow. I am essentially going mad i cant figure this out and despite the past couple weeks i keep working on other things and coming back to this. Despite my efforts and variations of different attempts. I cant seem to get the blasted thing to work.

*EDIT:* I forgot to add the actual error code that i am getting from the console so here it is. Again im trying different ways because i dont know anymore

[image: Error Type 1]

[image: Error Type 2]

[image: Error Type 3]

Here is the File Structure as well Custom Query Controller only gives the Index Page and has no real meat to it:

[image: File Desc]

So here is my code..

please note that if something is ungodly horrid i apologize. I have been whacking away at different possibilities

sqlAPIController.cs File

```
    // GET api/<controller>/<action>/<parameters>
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Get")]
    public int GetTrackAppearanceCount([FromUri(Name = "id")]string songTitle)
    {
        var result = db.Albums.Select(x => x.Tracks.Where(y => y.Title.Equals(songTitle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).Count();
        return Int32.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));

    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The Script in my View

```
<script>
var uri = 'api/sqlAPI';
//    path: 'GalleryPager?pageNumber={{#}}',
function find() {
    var songTitle = $('#songTitle').val();
    $.getJSON(uri + '/GetTrackAppearanceCount/' + songTitle)
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#query1').text(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#query1').text('Error: ' + err);
        });
}
</script>
```

Also! not sure if this matters but i saw this in another post so i figured i shall include it as well in this all

Web.Config

```
 <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
  <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
  <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You have not explained what the issue is! Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: YEA i saw that right after i was re-reading it to check for issues in what i explained! I have already edited it and attached the screen shots... im going to attach one more screen shot too

Comment: And that method is in `sqlAPIController`?

Comment: Yes it is called that. with each change i have changed its location back and forth to test that maybe it was a matter of its location and i have placed it in its own folder api or in the Controllers folder as well

Comment: what happens when you use `$.getJSON(uri + '/GetTrackAppearanceCount', { songTitle: songTitle}) {` and remove the `[FromUri(Name = "id")]` attribute

Comment: I will give that a try!

Comment: that did not work... unfortunately... i have reverted the changes back to reflect the original post as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had gone off what NightOwl888 had explained before... I was trying to work with my program as an API in MVC. I can wrap an API call and stuff but I can't really do what I was trying to do that way... Instead when I used tried with the following code below... it worked flawlessly.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetTrackAppearanceCount", "CustomQuery", new AjaxOptions
{

    UpdateTargetId = "contentArea",
    LoadingElementId = "loadingDiv",
    OnFailure = "AjaxFailure",
    OnBegin = "AjaxBegin",
    OnComplete = "AjaxComplete"

}, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h4>How many songs appear with the given track title</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="songTitle" name="songTitle" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Track Title" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="search" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Also to add further to this.. I had added in partial view pages that are just added into the dom when the Ajax executes.

Answer (score 1):

The default Web API route is **convention-based**. By default URLs are named the same as the controllers and actions they represent.

You have the route defined as:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And you are accessing the URL `/api/sqlAPI/GetTrackAppearanceCount`.

That means you need to have:

1. A controller named `SqlApiController`
2. An action method named `GetTrackAppearanceCount` in that controller

in order for Web API to locate it.

```
public class SqlApiController : ApiController
{
    public int GetTrackAppearanceCount(string id)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }
}
```

Since you don't have a controller with this name in your screenshot, that looks like your main issue.

> Note also that Web API is a separate framework from MVC and you cannot use their types interchangeably. For example, Web API would not be able to locate the controller if you inherit `Controller` instead of `ApiController`.

When building URLs on the UI and in controllers, you should always use the `UrlHelper`-based methods to generate them. This allows you to maintain all of your URLs in routing - if the URL changes (even based on where the application is deployed), you only need to make the change in one place.

```
var uri = '@Url.Action("GetTrackAppearanceCount", "SqlApi")';
function find() {
    var songTitle = $('#songTitle').val();
    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + songTitle)
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#query1').text(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#query1').text('Error: ' + err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Well I’m not sure if you’ve missed something but I do have a controller by the name sqlApicontroller though it’s in the api folder after each attempt to try something new I would also throw it into the controller folder

Comment: Other than that your comment is informative and I will try to use what you have told me as soon as I get up and eat some breakfast :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public int GetTrackAppearanceCount([FromUri]string songTitle)
```

Also change the ajax function

```
$.getJSON(uri + '/GetTrackAppearanceCount?songTitle=' + songTitle)
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, I think the problem is in your script. URI should have a '/' in the beginning, like `var uri = '/api/sqlAPI';`

Comment: I will give that a go right now and test it! though i think i have already tried that now that i think about it

Comment: yea thats a no go. it does not work with that change

Comment: One more thing I've noticed: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, but in defaults: `defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }`. Try to change name to id

Comment: oh i had name as id before as well but that doesnt work i think im going to leave it as id though now, but yea it doesnt fix it :(